# If $STU=Id_v$ find $T^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ is a vector space of finite dimension, $S,T,U:V\to V$ linear transformations. Suppose further that $STU=Id_v$. Show that $T$ is invertible and determine $T^{-1}$.
Show the statement is not necessarily true if the hypothesis that  is finite is removed.

Well I know that S, T and U are invertible by definition,  $STU=Id_v$ implies S, T and U are invertibles.

After, $(ST)U=S(TU)$ then $(TU)S=Id_v$ by definition, applying $T^{-1}$ in both sides $US=T^{-1}$ Am I right or wrong?

ANd Im stucked in the last point

Comment: How did you go from $S(TU) = Id_v$ to $(TU)S = Id_v$? Basically, the question is the following : why is it true in finite dimensions, that if $AB = I$ then $BA = I$? (i.e. a right inverse is the same as a left inverse, and therefore is an inverse)

Comment: You cannot apply $T^{-1}$ in order to prove $T^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон by definition  we know $ST=Id_w, TS=Id_v$ but by hypothesis the transformations V --> V the $S(TU)=Id_v, and (TU)S=Id_v$

Comment: @tkf nono, I know $T^{-1}$ exists because  1= det(STU) = det S det T det U, so all of S, T, and U have nonzero determinants and are invertible. I was trying to find what $T^-{1} is $

Comment: By hypothesis, $S(TU) = Id_v$, agreed. How do you go from this to $(TU)S= Id$?

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон well, the definition of book said If $V, W$ are vectorial spaces  and $T:V\to W$ and and $U:W\to V$ linear transformations then $TU=Id_w, UT=Id_v$ then i use that

Comment: Right, I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part you need to use the multiplicative property of the determinant.

For the second part consider operations on the vector space of infinite sequences of elements of the field.  To simplify matters let one of $S$ or $U$ be the identity.  Can you think of two simple operations you can perform on a sequence, whose composition is the identity one way, but not if you compose them the other way?